# ¿Porque cuando intento debugear en visual studio 2010, no me detiene la APP?

Tags: visual-studio

Bueno siempre que debuggeo me lo hace correctamente y queria ver a que se debia que no me debuggeara mi aplicacion de .net, ya que actualmente lo que intento hacer es saber que valor lleva una variable y lo ejecuto con un breakpoint en una parte de mi codigo pero nunca se detiene ahi, aunque si pasa por ahi mi ejecucion sino que lo ejecuta todo de manera normal, ya reinicie la aplicacion y verifique que si pasara por ahi, pero en ningun momento se detiene y de echo ya documente toda mi clase pero sigue sin hacer ningun cambio a la ventana actual.

Comment: añade tu error.

Comment: Lo mismo estás compilando en modo release... y si no hay información de debug los breakpoint no están operativos

Comment: @Manuel Morales no tengo error, no me aparece nada

Comment: @eferion como puedo saber en que modo estoy compilando

Comment: Junto al botón de Play debes tener un combobox en el que aparecen los modos de compilación... Normalmente son debug y release

Comment: @eferion si esta el combo como "Debug"

Comment: ¿puede ser que la ejecución no pase nunca por el breakpoint? Yo probaría a poner un punto de parada en el main para asegurarme

Comment: @eferion ya lo hice y tampoco lo activa y de echo mando llamar mi clase de c# a travez de un .js, asi que puse alertas en los metodos principales y tampoco lo ejecuta.

Comment: La app la tienes que ejecutar desde visual studio o bien hace un "_attach_" a la app en ejecución

Comment: Ponle messages box por donde quieres hacer el debug, sino lo mas probable es que cuando le hayas dado a iniciar y había errores le pusiste en si envés de no.

Comment: @David podrías editar tu pregunta e incluir el código de cómo lo llamas desde JavaScript y cuál es el método de tu clase que invocas.

Answer (score 1):

La pregunta es un poco ambigua, pero de los comentarios se puede deducir que quieres que se detenga en el código *javascript*, la integración de **Visual Studio** con navegadores para el ***debugging*** de código *javascript* es solo funcional con **Internet Explorer** o **Edge**, si quieres hacer debug en algún otro navegador como **Firefox** o **Chrome** tienes que usar sus propias herramientas integradas de desarrollador.

Para el ***debugging*** de ***code behind*** el navegador es indistinto; si el problema es en ***code behind*** si sería necesaria más información.